# Some of the following errors I found in my google app engine. Could anybody suggest some solutions for this??

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

After handling this request, the process that handled this request was found to be using too much memory and was terminated. This is likely to cause a new process to be used for the next request to your application. If you see this message frequently, you may have a memory leak in your application.

Full proto way too large to save, cleared frames.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using [appstats](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats), and its recording module cannot save all the data because it too big. Only part of the data will be available.